# Turn off tab lines in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Unfortunately I did some rare keyboard combination and I activated what it is marked in the image.

Can I deactivate it again? which option is it? or keyboard combination.

I am using Visual Studio 2010

[image]

Comment: Go to "Edit - Adanced - View White Space" (ctrl - E, S) to toggle back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to turn it off again under Edit> Advanced> View White Space.
Ctrl+E,S should be the keyboard shortcut to toggle it.